# Validate date of birth in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, validation, datepicker

I've created a form using Flutter which has date picker.[image]

User is supposed to pick his/her date of birth using it to make sure if the user is 16 and above. How do I validate date of birth to age 16?

Here are the parts of the code:

```
class _WelcomeScreenState extends State<WelcomeScreen> {
  TextEditingController dateinput = TextEditingController();
  final formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  String name = "";

  @override
  void initState() {
    dateinput.text = ""; //set the initial value of text field
    super.initState();
  }
```

--

```
GestureDetector(
                child: TextField(
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                  controller:
                      dateinput, //editing controller of this TextField
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                      labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                      icon: Icon(Icons.calendar_today),
                      iconColor: Colors.white, //icon of text field
                      labelText: "Enter Date Of Birth" //label text of field
                      ),
                  readOnly:
                      true, //set it true, so that user will not able to edit text
                  onTap: () async {
                    DateTime? pickedDate = await showDatePicker(
                        context: context,
                        initialDate: DateTime.now(),
                        firstDate: DateTime(
                            1900), //DateTime.now() - not to allow to choose before today.
                        lastDate: DateTime(2040));

                    if (pickedDate != null) {
                      print(
                          pickedDate); //pickedDate output format => 2021-03-10 00:00:00.000
                      String formattedDate =
                          DateFormat('dd-MM-yyyy').format(pickedDate);
                      print(
                          formattedDate); //formatted date output using intl package =>  2021-03-16
                      //you can implement different kind of Date Format here according to your requirement

                  setState(() {
                    dateinput.text =
                        formattedDate; //set output date to TextField value.
                  });
                } else {
                  print("Date is not selected");
                }
              },
            ),
          ),
```

Answer (score 2):

A naive approach would be to just construct a `DateTime` object from the selected birth date and to then compute `DateTime.now().difference(birthDate).inDays / 365`.  That doesn't account for leap days, and maybe it's close enough, but it's *not how a human would compute age*.

When attempting to solve a programming problem, one of the first things you usually should ask yourself is: How would you solve this without a computer?

To determine if someone is at least 16 years old, you would take the current date, subtract 16 from the year, use the same month and day<sup>1</sup>, and see if their birthday is on or before that date, ignoring the time.  So just do that:

```dart
extension IsAtLeastYearsOld on DateTime {
  bool isAtLeastYearsOld(int years) {
    var now = DateTime.now();
    var boundaryDate = DateTime(now.year - years, now.month, now.day);

    // Discard the time from [this].
    var thisDate = DateTime(year, month, day);

    // Did [thisDate] occur on or before [boundaryDate]?
    return thisDate.compareTo(boundaryDate) <= 0;
  }
}

void main() {
  // The results below were obtained with 2022-06-11 as the current date.
  print(DateTime(2006, 6, 10).isAtLeastYearsOld(16)); // Prints: true
  print(DateTime(2006, 6, 11).isAtLeastYearsOld(16)); // Prints: true
  print(DateTime(2006, 6, 12).isAtLeastYearsOld(16)); // Prints: false
}
```

---

<sup>1</sup> This should be fine even if the current date is a leap day since `DateTime` will convert February 29 into March 1 for non-leap years.

Answer (score 1):

With a function for calculate :

```
class _WelcomeScreenState extends State<WelcomeScreen> {
  TextEditingController dateinput = TextEditingController();
  final formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  String name = "";

  @override
  void initState() {
    dateinput.text = ""; //set the initial value of text field
    super.initState();
  }

  int calculateAge(DateTime birthDate) {
    DateTime currentDate = DateTime.now();
    int age = currentDate.year - birthDate.year;
    if (birthDate.month > currentDate.month) {
      age--;
    } else if (currentDate.month == birthDate.month) {
      if (birthDate.day > currentDate.day) {
        age--;
      }
    }
    return age;
  }
}
```

And in your TextField :

```
GestureDetector(
    child: TextFormField(
        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
        controller: dateinput, //editing controller of this TextField
        decoration: InputDecoration(
            labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
            icon: Icon(Icons.calendar_today),
            iconColor: Colors.white, //icon of text field
            labelText: "Enter Date Of Birth" //label text of field
        ),
        readOnly: true, //set it true, so that user will not able to edit text
        validator: (value) {
            if (calculateAge(DateTime.parse(value)) < 16 || value.isEmpty) {
                return 'Please enter date.';
            }
            return null;
        },
        onTap: () async {
            DateTime? pickedDate = await showDatePicker(
                context: context,
                initialDate: DateTime.now(),
                firstDate: DateTime(1900), //DateTime.now() - not to allow to choose before today.
                lastDate: DateTime(2040));
            if (pickedDate != null) {
                print(pickedDate); //pickedDate output format => 2021-03-10 00:00:00.000
                String formattedDate = DateFormat('dd-MM-yyyy').format(pickedDate);
                print(formattedDate); //formatted date output using intl package =>  2021-03-16
                //you can implement different kind of Date Format here according to your requirement
                setState(() => dateinput.text = formattedDate);
            } else {
                print("Date is not selected");
            }
        },
    ),
),
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate how and where to insert this function in my code?

Comment: I updated my post for insert function in your code

Comment: An error occurs while validating. In `if (calculateAge(value) < 16` , an error occurs for value. It says "The argument type 'String?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'DateTime'."

Comment: If value is String modify to : `calculateAge(DateTime.pasre(value))`

Comment: No errors after modifying, but an exception has occurred saying invalid date format.

Comment: You can use DateFormat for to have the good format : `DateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").parse(value)`